# Binary Search on a character of type '/'

Tags: python, numpy, web-scraping

I am having this issue in binary search where I am unable to recognize the character '/' as a string or an int. So comparison is nearly impossible. I am curious what the thoughts are for this problem. How would I perform a binary search on a url in python?

```
url1 = "https://diversity.google"
url2 = "https://www.aboutamazon.com/workplace/diversity-inclusion"
url3 = "https://www.indeed.com/q-Diversity-jobs.html?vjk=ba073b4704d48c67"
url4 = "https://careers.linkedin.com/diversity-and-inclusion"
url5 = "https://github.com/about/diversity"
url6 = "https://www.apple.com/diversity/"
url7 ="https://www.samsung.com/us/about-us/diversity-and-inclusion/"
url8 = "https://diversity.fb.com"
url9 ="instagram:none"
url10 = "https://careers.twitter.com/en/diversity.html"


data = [url1,url2,url3,url4,url5,url6,url7,url8,url9,url10]

print(data)
def binary_search(i, data, low, high, x):
  mid = (high+low) / 2

  if data[i][mid] > x:
    return binary_search(data, low, mid-1, x)
    
  elif data[i] [mid] < x:
      return binary_search(data, mid+1, high, x)

  else:
    return mid


error:

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-30-fb856fb84489> in <module>()
      9   high = [i][-1]
     10 
---> 11   foundOne = binary_search(i,data,low,high,x)
     12 
     13   if (foundOne == x):

<ipython-input-29-739df621f0c5> in binary_search(i, data, low, high, x)
     20 print(data)
     21 def binary_search(i, data, low, high, x):
---> 22   mid = (high+low) / 2
     23 
     24   if data[i][mid] > x:

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'int'
```

*********************(update)***************************

This is where I call it.Apologies for not including it.

```
x = '/'
 



counterData = []

counter = 0
for i in data:
  low = [i][0]
  high = [i][-1]
  
  foundOne = binary_search(i,data,low,high,x)

  
  if (foundOne == x):
    counter += 1
  else:
    counter += 0
  
counterData.append(counter)
```

Comment: Can you tell us the way you Call your function ? what variables you are passing to the function?

Comment: Create and post your [mcve].

Comment: Showed the function call. Not sure if it notifies you when I edit it.

Comment: First, an array must be sorted before you can do a binary search.  Second, `low` and `high` need to be the INDEXES of the start and end points, not the STRINGS.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a version that works.  You can see it searches for each entry in turn, and then prints the index.

When I'm doing a search, I usually try to call the thing being searched the "haystack", and the thing I'm searching for the "needle".

Also, your function doesn't handle the case where the needle is not found in the haystack.

```
url1 = "https://diversity.google"
url2 = "https://www.aboutamazon.com/workplace/diversity-inclusion"
url3 = "https://www.indeed.com/q-Diversity-jobs.html?vjk=ba073b4704d48c67"
url4 = "https://careers.linkedin.com/diversity-and-inclusion"
url5 = "https://github.com/about/diversity"
url6 = "https://www.apple.com/diversity/"
url7 = "https://www.samsung.com/us/about-us/diversity-and-inclusion/"
url8 = "https://diversity.fb.com"
url9 = "instagram:none"
url10 = "https://careers.twitter.com/en/diversity.html"


data = [url1,url2,url3,url4,url5,url6,url7,url8,url9,url10]
data.sort()

def binary_search(haystack, low, high, needle):
    if high < low:
        return -1

    mid = (high+low) // 2

    if haystack[mid] > needle:
        return binary_search(haystack, low, mid-1, needle)
    elif haystack[mid] < needle:
        return binary_search(haystack, mid+1, high, needle)
    else:
        return mid

for i in data:
    foundOne = binary_search(data, 0, len(data)-1, i)
    print(i, foundOne)
```

Output:

```
https://careers.linkedin.com/diversity-and-inclusion 0
https://careers.twitter.com/en/diversity.html 1
https://diversity.fb.com 2
https://diversity.google 3
https://github.com/about/diversity 4
https://www.aboutamazon.com/workplace/diversity-inclusion 5
https://www.apple.com/diversity/ 6
https://www.indeed.com/q-Diversity-jobs.html?vjk=ba073b4704d48c67 7
https://www.samsung.com/us/about-us/diversity-and-inclusion/ 8
instagram:none 9
```